# Dual-homed vCenter 6.0 server appliance

Tags: vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

I've installed the VCSA 6.0.  Now, I'd like to add a second NIC to it and be able to access the vCenter Web UI from both networks.  I've followed the steps here to add a second NIC to the vCenter and configure the IP address.  http://easi123.4realit.nl/2015/12/add-a-second-nic-to-vmware-vcenter-server-appliance-6-0/

However, I can't access the Web GUI or the Desktop client from the outside network using the second address.  I've also tried rebooting the appliance to make sure the web server sees that there are 2 networks.  Can someone point me to the configuration or the firewall that needs to be changed to allow access from 2 different networks?

Comment: What did VMware support say about this?

Comment: This is not a normal use case. Do you have the ability to _route_ to the appropriate networks?

Comment: You mention a second network and then you mention an outside network. Those are kind of two different things. If I have a host that is physically connected to two different networks then neither of those networks is an outside network. If my webserver on that host is configured to listen on the ip addresses for both network interface cards then I ought to be able to connect to that webserver using either ip address (from the appropriate network). How about giving us some more detail on the exact configuration of the vCenter appliance and your networks. A network diagram would be helpful too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In vSphere 6.0 we have the ability to have multiple TCP/IP stacks which means you can have multiple default gateways. This is an ESX host construct, though, so not sure how that relates to vCSA (or why TheCompWiz brought that up).

It is completely unsupported to add in a 2nd NIC to the vCSA. However, this is something we're looking at and could be added in the future. If you want this type of ability then please let your TAM, SE, or open an SR to let us know and it can be tracked.